# Retrieving name and/or text from a WinForms control using the WinAPI (CE)

Tags: c#, winapi, compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I am trying to traverse the controls of a WinForms form (Windows CE) and retrieve/match their textual contents and names (that is, the `Name` property assigned to the WinForms `Control` object).

I do this from within a different process, thus WinAPI.

For traversing and for retrieving the text I wrote the following code. `TextPresent` uses `DescendantControls` for the traversing and `Text` to retrieve the text. I am fairly confident that the traversing code works correctly already - if not, please let me know. However, all of the controls that are returned have an empty text.

The code can be used as follows:

```
var foregroundWindow = new WinCEControl(GetForegroundWindow()); // working properly
Assert.That("The Window Title", foregroundWindow.Text); // working properly
Assert.That(manorMenu.TextPresent("Text to find")); // not working although /
    // "Text to find" is a value within the control tree of the window.
```

As for the name, I do not even know how to retrieve it at all. So far my searching was unsuccessful.

```
public class WinCEControl
{
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

    private const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
    private const uint GW_CHILD = 5;
    private const uint GW_HWNDLAST = 1;
    private const uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;

    public WinCEControl(IntPtr handle)
    {
        this.Handle = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_GETTEXT, stringBuilder.Capacity, stringBuilder);
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<WinCEControl> Children()
    {
        var childHandle = GetWindow(Handle, GW_CHILD);

        if (childHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var lastHandle = GetWindow(childHandle, GW_HWNDLAST);

        while (childHandle != lastHandle)
        {
            yield return new WinCEWindow(childHandle);

            childHandle = GetWindow(childHandle, GW_HWNDNEXT);
        }

        yield return new WinCEWindow(lastHandle);
    }

    public IEnumerable<WinCEControl> DescendantControls()
    {
        var nodes = new Queue<WinCEControl>(new[] { this });
        while (nodes.Any())
        {
            var node = nodes.Dequeue();

            if (node != this)
            {
                yield return node;
            }

            foreach (var n in node.Children()) nodes.Enqueue(n);
        }
    }

    public bool TextPresent(string text)
    {
        foreach (var descendantControl in DescendantControls())
        {
            if (descendantControl.Text == text)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

My goal is to be able to perform UI tests against a running application on the CE device. If there is a solid C# library to achieve the same which works on Windows CE I am very hear.

*Update:* As mentioned in my comment I have failed to find a library or framework for automating foreign WinForms processes on the Win CE. I tried the "simple-wince-gui-automation" and it fails to retrieve the texts, too.

Comment: Writing this kind of code yourself is unwise, this problem has of course been solved.  Google "windows ce ui automation library" to get ahead.

Comment: I have started to partially answer with C++ code using WinApi to get the "name" property of a WinForm Object. But it involves using the following APIs, RegisterWindowMessage, GetWindowThreadProcessId, OpenProcess, VirtualAllocEx, SendMessage, ReadProcessMemory, VirtualFreeEx and CloseHandle... May be NOT ok on Windows CE (don't know). Are you interested?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/simple-wince-gui-automation/

Comment: @Hans: You are perfectly right in this regard. I took your google query and found the DATK/WMTK as well as the simple-wince-gui-automation quoted by ctacke. Unfortunately the DATK/WMTK are overly complicated and "underly" documented and I did not manage to make them run. The simple-wince-gui-automation looks slick and lightweight but suffers of exactly the same issue that I described in my question: All elements retrieved have empty texts.